# Working on an app that seems to keep crashing from not being able to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, xml, android-layout

So i am trying to build a story telling app and it seems to keep crashing and I have not found a solution to my problem yet. I believe that it due to my array class called Page or something is wrong when it is trying to call drawables from my resources.

I have tried re writing my entire code, changing values anything that I know of.

This is one of the class where i created an array to hold my vaules i used a constructor to better story things into the array.

```
public class Story {

    private Page[] pages;

    public Story(){
        pages = new Page[7];

       pages[0] = new Page(R.drawable.page0,
               R.string.page0,
               new Choice(R.string.page0_choice1,1),
               new Choice(R.string.page0_choice2,2));
        pages[1] = new Page(R.drawable.page1,
                R.string.page1,
                new Choice(R.string.page1_choice1, 3),
                new Choice(R.string.page1_choice2, 4));

        pages[2] = new Page(R.drawable.page2,
                R.string.page2,
                new Choice(R.string.page2_choice1, 4),
                new Choice(R.string.page2_choice2, 6));

        pages[3] = new Page(R.drawable.page3,
                R.string.page3,
                new Choice(R.string.page3_choice1, 4),
                new Choice(R.string.page3_choice2, 5));

        pages[4] = new Page(R.drawable.page4,
                R.string.page4,
                new Choice(R.string.page4_choice1, 5),
                new Choice(R.string.page4_choice2, 6));

        pages[5] = new Page(R.drawable.page5, R.string.page5);

        pages[6] = new Page(R.drawable.page6, R.string.page6);
    }

    public Page getPage(int pageNumber) {
        if(pageNumber >= pages.length) {
            pageNumber = 0;
        }
        return pages[pageNumber];
```

This is another class withing my code that seems to be where my error is coming from I have tried messing with this class the most.

```
public class StoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = StoryActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Story story;
    public ImageView storyImageView;
    private TextView storyTextView;
    private Button choice1Button;
    private Button choice2Button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        storyImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.storyImageView);
        storyTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.storyTextView);
        choice1Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice1Button);
        choice2Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice2Button);

        // get the intent used to start this activity

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.key_name));
        if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
            name = "Friend";
        }
        Log.d(TAG, name);

        story = new Story();
        loadPage(0);


    }

    private void loadPage(int pageNumber) {
        Page page = story.getPage(pageNumber);

        Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, page.getImageId());
        storyImageView.setImageDrawable(image);

    }
}
```

I expect the app to be able to press the next button without crashing the message i get from the crash log is.

```
2019-07-25 00:02:39.729 4655-4655/com.thomas.interactivestory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.thomas.interactivestory, PID: 4655
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thomas.interactivestory/com.thomas.interactivestory.ui.StoryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at com.thomas.interactivestory.ui.StoryActivity.loadPage(StoryActivity.java:58)
        at com.thomas.interactivestory.ui.StoryActivity.onCreate(StoryActivity.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is my activity_Main.xml file hopefully this help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="com.thomas.interactivestory.ui.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titleImageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/signals_from_mars_title_image"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_title" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/StartButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/start_your_adventure"
        android:textColor="#2A8AEC"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/NameEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
        android:maxLength="30"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/StartButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should read the error message. It clearly states that you're trying to call a method `setImageDrawable` on a `null` instance of `ImageView` (`storyImageView`).


1. Are you sure there is a `View` with id `storyImageView` inside your `activity_main`? Why don't you attach it as well (the `activity_main` xml).


2. Why is `storyImageView` public? Are you doing some funky business with it from "outside" of the `StoryActivity`?

Comment: Lol no i just changed the storyImageView back to private that was something I just tried to do to fix the problem

Comment: I also add my activity main xml

Comment: Actually I just checked you were right in my activity Main xml file I did not name it to storyImageView Thank you  so much!!! I been so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `activity_main.xml` is missing `storyImageView`.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); I need to replace R.layout.activity_main with R.layout.activity_story; I was calling the wrong xml class so everything was saying it has nothing to point to

Answer (score 0):

Turns out inside of my activity_main.xml file I did not rename the ImageView to storyImageView it was still set to default and explains why my code kept crashing. I was trying to change an Id in a class that I never set that why it was pointing to nothing.

Thanks Bartek Lipinski!!!

Comment: I posted the answer :)